# How open parentheses in if expression?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-like

I have expression. How I can open or rewrite this?

```
if not ((A or B) and PAR like '%3%') then
    --do some code
end if;
```

Can do this more simple?
Please, give me a link for another expressions as example.

Comment: What does "open" mean?

Comment: Clean expression from "not", from "(" and ")".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be close to what you're looking for:

```
IF A = FALSE AND B = FALSE AND REGEXP_LIKE(PAR, '[^3]') THEN
  -- code here
END IF;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks. What about oracle9i?

Comment: For 9i you can use the INSTR function instead of REGEXP_LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
if(A!=true or B!=true)
    if(REGEXP_LIKE(name,'[^r]'))
    /*code has to be written here*/
    end if;
end if;
```